# Exchange 2013 - Grant delegation to security group?

Tags: active-directory, permissions, exchange, exchange-2013

One of our clients needs all users with a mailbox to be granted `Full Access` and `Send on Behalf` permissions to another shared mailbox.

The easiest way to do this would be to give a security group the needed permissions, but Exchange 2013 is only allowing delegates that are users.  I've tried via ECP and the following (assuming "sharedemail" is the shared mailbox and "AllUsersSecGroup" is an AD Security Group):

`Set-Mailbox -Identity "sharedemail" -GrantSendOnBehalfTo "AllUsersSecGroup"`

I can't use `Add-MailboxPermission` because there's no operator for `Group` instead of `User`.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are setting the permission to a group makes no difference. You can still use add-mailboxpermission and enter the group name as the user. I usually enter the group name as domain\alias.